# Calculating EER with anomaly detection using LSTM in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have dataset features evaluated from the touch screen and built-in sensors on smartphones. I want to implement an anomaly detection code using LSTM autoencoder in python to compute EER value (Equal Error Rate) less than 10%. The training dataset has the size of the genuine user with zeros labels. However, the test dataset includes samples of both the genuine user and anomaly users. We labeled genuine user's samples with zeros and anomaly users' samples with ones.

Data structure:

X_train from the genuine user has the shape (4814,158) which means (# of samples (raws), # of features (columns)).
Y_train has the shape (4814,1), all zeros.

X_test include total (3000,158) where (1500,158) from the genuine user and (1500,158)from the other anomaly users.

Y_test (3000,1) where the first (1500,1) labels are zeros represent the genuine user and the remaining (1500,1) labels are ones represent the other anomaly users.

Normalization process
I used the Standardscalre normalization method to fit and transform training data, then transform the test dataset.

```
# import libraries
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from numpy.random import seed
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
from Keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed,
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model
from keras import regularizers

# normalize the data
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train )
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train )
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

## reshape inputs for LSTM [samples, timesteps, features]

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
print("Training data shape:", X_train.shape)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])
print("Test data shape:", X_test.shape)
```

Training data shape: (4814, 1, 158),
Test data shape: (3000, 1, 158)

## define the autoencoder network model

```
def autoencoder_model(X):
   inputs = Input(shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
   L1 = LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, 
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00))(inputs)
   L2 = LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)(L1)
   L3 = RepeatVector(X.shape[1])(L2)
   L4 = LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(L3)
   L5 = LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(L4)
   output = TimeDistributed(Dense(X.shape[2]))(L5)    
   model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
   return model
```

## create the autoencoder model

```
model = autoencoder_model(X_train)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
model.summary()
```

## fit the model to the data

```
nb_epochs = 100
batch_size = 10
history = model.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=nb_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, 
validation_split=0.05).history
```

## calculate the loss on the test set

```
X_pred = model.predict(X_test)
X_pred = X_pred.reshape(X_pred.shape[0], X_pred.shape[2])
X_pred = pd.DataFrame(X_pred, columns=test.columns)
X_pred.index = test.index
scored = pd.DataFrame(index=test.index)
Xtest = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[2])
scored['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(X_pred-Xtest), axis = 1)
```

## Function to compute EER based on FAR and FRR values

```
def find_EER(far, frr):
   far_optimum = 0
   frr_optimum = 0
   x = np.absolute((np.array(far) - np.array(frr)))
   print("diff_far_frr=", x)
   print("min_diff_far_frr=", min(x))
   y = np.nanargmin(x)
   print("index of min difference=", y)
   far_optimum = far[y]
   frr_optimum = frr[y]
   return far_optimum, frr_optimum
```

## Compute FPR, TPR, and Thresholds using ROC_cureve from sci-kit learn

```
fpr, tpr,  threshold = metrics.roc_curve(Y_test, scored, pos_label=1)
fnr = 1 - tpr # get FNR , however FPR is same as FAR
far_optimum, frr_optimum = find_EER(fpr, fnr)
print("far_optimum = ", far_optimum)
print("frr_optimum = ", frr_optimum)
EER = max(far_optimum, frr_optimum)
EER_scores.append(EER*100)
HTER = 0.5 * (far_optimum + frr_optimum)
HTER_scores.append(HTER*100)
print("EER_scores: maximum of the FAR OR FRR when |FAR -FRR| is minimized ", EER_scores)
print("HTER_scores (0.5 * (FAR+FRR)*100: ", HTER_scores)

#**************End of the code************#
```

When I run the model it gives EER values range from 20 to 30%. It depends on the dataset of the user. This range seems very high to my requirement and I want to improve the model to achieve EER less than 10%.

I tried to change the number of layers, nodes, epochs, and batch_size, hundreds of times but still give me EER values in the same range. :(

Is there something wrong with the code?
Can anyone help me what shall I change in the model to get lower EER values?

Output sample:

[image]

[image]